# Why is MigraDoc generating a blank pdf in my asp.net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdfsharp, migradoc

I have the following code in my attempts to create a PDF:

```
    public static MemoryStream Test()
    {
        var document = new Document();
        document.Info.Title = "Test Report";
        document.Info.Subject = "blah";
        document.Info.Author = "Me";
        //new CoverPageSummarySection().AddToDocument(document, new int[0], 2004);

        Style style = document.Styles["Normal"];
        style.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
        style = document.Styles["Heading1"];
        style.Font.Name = "Tahoma";
        style.Font.Size = 14;
        style.Font.Bold = true;
        style.Font.Color = Colors.DarkBlue;
        style.ParagraphFormat.PageBreakBefore = true;
        style.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6;

        var section = document.AddSection();
        var p = section.AddParagraph("test");
        p.AddText("Testing 1234");

        var renderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true, PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
        renderer.Document = document;
        renderer.RenderDocument();

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        renderer.PdfDocument.Save(ms, false);
        return ms;
    }
```

The resulting pdf is blank.  I can view the properties and the `document.Info` fields are showing correctly in my PDF, but I can't see any text on my page.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Edit:** So it appears that the issue has something to do with saving to a memory stream.  When I replace `renderer.PdfDocument.Save(ms, false);` to `renderer.PdfDocument.Save("e:\\test.pdf");` it saves it correctly at test.pdf.

My code to save the memory stream to the asp.net output is:

```
        var stream = TestReportGen.Test();

        // Set the content headers
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=testReport.pdf");

        stream.WriteTo(HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream);
        stream.Close();

        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Is the issue with how I'm sending back the memorystream or what?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a valid MigraDoc document, the following should work:

```
PdfDocumentRenderer renderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true, PdfFontEmbedding.Always);
renderer.Document = document;
renderer.RenderDocument();

// Send PDF to browser
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
renderer.PdfDocument.Save(stream, false);
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-length", stream.Length.ToString());
Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
Response.Flush();
stream.Close();
Response.End();
```

Comment: How would you do this in an MVC app?

Answer (score 1):

The majority of my problems with streams are solved by `Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)`.

Comment: Nope, Seeking prior to my write did not seem to fix the issue :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not an ASP.NET expert, but there is a working web server sample included with PDFsharp:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/Clock-sample.ashx

I don't know whether it's the missing `content-length` that makes the difference.

`Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)` was missing with early versions of PDFsharp, but is done automatically in the current version.